# Making Select2 pillbox control more accessible compliant and want feedback (bring your screen reader)

Tags: jquery, accessibility, jquery-select2, screen-readers, mutation-observers

I am looking for feedback on screen reader improvements for the code/example below.

The Select2 pillbox control needs to be more accessible.  They have an open issues on this subject [Select2 Issue Page](https://github.com/select2/select2/issues/3744) and after I get more feedback will submit change suggestions to them (or submit a branch with the changes).

My Goals in the following code is:

1. Start to Finish Experience
2. When user first gets to control it needs to read out load what items are select
     a.The Search Box Input is in the last

   and causes confusion, will uses ROLE to change this.

   Give user 1 simple way to remove item or all selected items
       a. screen reader hide individual remove, too much confusion caused having many ways to do it.

   When input selected give clear instructions for usage (filter list, open list, how to navigate)

   When dynamically generated available item open and user navigates thought them, tell them what is selected and not selected.
       a. Double check Aria tag usage. 
       b. Tell User they can select and un-select items

My working example is on fiddlejs [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nonoandy/z94dgom7/)

Also here is a working copy

```js
//- nonoandy
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this probobly can be done wiht adapters or smarter ways that will take me a lot longer to do lol. -nonoandy

  //using this class like a flag to stop circuler reference
  var updatedHtmlClass = "select2-skipme";

  //init the select2 control
  var select2Orginal = $(".select2Control");
  select2Orginal.select2();

  //find the real select2 control
  var select2Control = $(".select2Control").next();

  //When screen reader user is arrowing through page (not tabbing through) this will explain the UL
  var select2UlDesc = select2Control.find("span.select2-selection");
  select2UlDesc.prepend("<span class='sr-only'>Selected Items</span>");

  //1. Change the role of the <li> that contains the SearchBox, so screen reader count and reading is more accurate. 
  //2. Warning! I would like to move the SearchBox out of the <UL> and the remove all BUT Select2 doesnt' work right if you move it (change to div would be best too)
  var searchBoxLi = select2Control.find("li.select2-search");
  var searchBoxInput = select2Control.find("input.select2-search__field");
  if (searchBoxLi) {
    //making sure screen reader treat the searchbox <li> as a item
    searchBoxLi.attr("role", "search");

    //adding in flag for future skips
    searchBoxLi.addClass(updatedHtmlClass);
    var searchBoxInput = select2Control.find("input.select2-search__field");
    if (searchBoxInput) {
      //adding in screen reader description to help explain purpose of search box
      var searchDescId = select2Orginal.id + "_SearchBox_desc";
      searchBoxInput.attr("aria-describedby", searchDescId);
      searchBoxLi.append("<div id='" + searchDescId + "' class='sr-only'>Optionally you can type to filter and after activating press Up or Down arrows to select or unselect items</div>")
    }
  }

  //Not tested Yet
  //This <span> is inside the <ul> which isn't good syntax but doens't seem to mess with JAWS screen readers
  var clearAllSpan = select2Control.find("span.select2-selection__clear");
  if (clearAllSpan) {
    clearAllSpan.text("<i class='fas fa-times' aria-hidden='true'></i><span class='sr-only'>Remove all items</span>");
  }

  //When a <li> is added after selection, we need to do a few things
  //1. Update the remove <span> with icon because I like that better
  //2. Aria Hide the  remove-span and leave just selected text for screen readers to find.
  //    WHY!! because they can select and unselect in the dropdown and there is a "remove all" option.  Adding too much stuff makes it confusing. (less is more)
  //3. add class-flags in because circular referenes 
  var selectUl = select2Control.find("ul.select2-selection__rendered");
  $(selectUl).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function(e) {
    //need "Hooks" or events for custom code when a <li> is added
    //DOMNodeInserted is old but faster to uses than MutationObserver #ClearnUp
    if (e.currentTarget.className.indexOf(updatedHtmlClass) == -1) {
      e.currentTarget.className += " " + updatedHtmlClass;
      var newRemoveItemHtml = "<span aria-hidden='true' class='select2-selection__choice__remove' role='presentation' title='Remove " + e.currentTarget.title + "'><i class='fas fa-times'></i></span>" + e.currentTarget.title;
      if (e.currentTarget.innerHTML.indexOf(updatedHtmlClass) == -1) {
        e.currentTarget.innerHTML = newRemoveItemHtml;
      }
    }
  });


  //Select2 dynamically shows a dropdown for selecting or unselecting items
  //I want to make sure this list of items is clearly marked as 'Selected' or 'Not Selected' 
  $('select').on('select2:open', function(e) {
    var dynamixULId = "#" + select2Control.find(".select2-selection").attr("aria-owns");
    $(dynamixULId).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'li', function(e) {
      //AGAIN! need "Hooks" or events for custom code when a <li> is added
      //DOMNodeInserted is old but faster to uses than MutationObserver #ClearnUp
      var currentLi = $(e.currentTarget);

      //it seems the aria-selected is changed after the controls are loaded, so I need a even to trigger and update screen reader text too.
      //attrchange is a older extention there could be better ways of doing this #ResearchLater 
      $(currentLi).attrchange({
        trackValues: true,
        callback: function(event) {
          if (event.attributeName == "aria-selected") {
            if (!currentLi.attr("data-select2-data")) {
              currentLi.attr("data-select2-data", currentLi.text())
            }
            //the aria-selected will make the screen reader say "not selected"
            currentLi.html("<span class='sr-only'>" +
              ((event.newValue == "true") ? "Selected" : "") +
              "</span>" +
              currentLi.attr("data-select2-data"));
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  /* background: #20262E;*/
  padding: 30px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
.select2-results__option[aria-selected="true"]:before {
    content: '\f14a';
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    font-weight: 600;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/attrchange/2.0.1/attrchange.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>



<div id="banner-message">
  <h1>Making the Select2 control more accessible!</h1>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label for="select2Control">
 Pick People 
</label>
  <select id="select2Control" class="select2Control form-control" name="things[]" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Andy</option>
    <option value="2">Bob</option>
    <option value="3">Russ</option>
    <option value="4">Dave</option>
    <option value="5">Matt</option>
    <option value="6">Adam</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems off-topic on SO, might be better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe but accessibility is a real issues that public facing web sites are getting sued daily over.  Post like this help people, I beat I have googled this 100 times in the years.  The problems are logically and syntax errors but to test them you need real humans and a lot of different tools due to poor common practices.
I posted here to do two things 1. help find weak places in my code  2. help others that are looking for something similar and/or update the original code to fix for everyone.

Comment: Now I see this is definitely off-topic for Stackverflow so it'll be closed and automatically removed after a while. You'll have to rework it into a Q/A format.

Answer (score 0):

This question is obsolete as the Select2 product has been updated to handle accessibility better.

My suggest would be, making sure to have the latest version of there product.